# Selenium remote webdriver error when running a build with ant/ivy

Tags: java, ant, selenium, ivy

Here is my error message, I'll explain below.

```
<error message="Mouse is not implemented yet for the remote WebDriver." type="java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException">java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Mouse is not implemented yet for the remote WebDriver
```

The problem is when I run my selenium automation scripts using ant/ivy I get that error. This code runs fine on it's own, but i'm trying to use ant/ivy to get it built so I can run it on jenkins. It does build ok, I get this problem when running the build suite.

I have the following selenium packages being pulled from the central repository

```
<dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-server" rev="2.5.0"/>
<dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-java" rev="2.5.0"/>
<dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-firefox-driver" rev="2.5.0"/>
<dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-api" rev="2.5.0"/>
<dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-remote-client" rev="2.0b1"/>
<dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-remote-driver" rev="2.5.0" >
<artifact name="selenium-remote-driver" type="jar" />
</dependency>
<dependency org="org.seleniumhq.webdriver" name="webdriver-common" rev="0.9.7376" >
<artifact name="webdriver-common" type="jar" />
</dependency>
<dependency org="org.seleniumhq.webdriver" name="webdriver-remote-client" rev="0.9.7376" >
<artifact name="webdriver-remote-client" type="jar" />
</dependency>
<dependency org="org.seleniumhq.webdriver" name="webdriver-remote-server" rev="0.9.7376" >
<artifact name="webdriver-remote-server" type="jar" />
</dependency>
<dependency org="org.seleniumhq.webdriver" name="webdriver-remote-common" rev="0.9.7376" >
<artifact name="webdriver-remote-common" type="jar" />
```

I wasn't able to find a place in the central repository to pull down the selenium-server-standalone.jar so I don't have that. Is there a package that might work better or a workaround for this issues?

Please let me know if my question is not clear enough, I'm new to ant/ivy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that you are hitting [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1160)?  It seems like you are using an older version (2.5.0) of most of those Selenium packages. According to [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3a%22org.seleniumhq.selenium%22) those packages are all at version 2.19.0 now. Maybe updating to the most recent ones may fix the problem.

Comment: After talking to someone at selenium they fixed this issue in 2.11, but this was the only answer and it would have fixed the problem, so I'll mark this as the answer and bounty. Thanks for helping.